# Update Logic Causes WF to Cancel

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, update, item-updating

For testing purposes I created a VERY simple WF due to the error I'm getting. I have a Designer 2013 List WF that Runs on the Checked Items List shown below:

[image]

The logic is that it will create an item in the Requests List. The only column, aside from Title, that the Create logic is making is the RequestStatus which is set to CurrentItem:RequestStatus.

Stage 1 of the WF runs perfectly. But as soon as I change the RequestStatus to Investigation the WF runs the first log on Stage 2 but then shows me this error displayed below:

[image]

I thought my Update logic is sound but I'm not sure. Below is the Update logic in WF:

[image]

Can anyone assist in what could be contributing to the WF producing the error on Stage 2?

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely locked for editing from when it was created. If you try to update the same item twice fairly close together in a workflow, the second time you'll be locked out. Try adding a 5 minute pause.

Comment: Hi Erin. I have tested with the Pause prior to Update and I still get the error. please advise on what I can try.

Comment: Add the full error from your ULS log